# Read public key from certificate with nodejs

Tags: vb.net, node.js, openssl

I need to read an public key from an certificate in nodejs to encrypt data:

```
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('keys/certificate.cer');

var cipher = ursa.createPublicKey(----->certificate.getPulicKey()<------);
var symmetric = crypto.randomBytes(128);
var Nonce = new Buffer(cipher.encrypt(symmetric, "utf8", "utf8")).toString('base64');

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', symmetric);
cipher.update("Transporte", 'utf8', 'base64');
var Password = cipher.final('base64');

var d = new Date();
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', symmetric);
cipher.update(d.toUTCString(), 'utf8', 'base64');
var Created = cipher.final('base64');
```

Something like:

```
Dim certCP As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
certCP.Import(certificate)
Dim publicKey As String = certCP.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(False)
```

in VB...

Any idea how to do that in nodejs?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for the exact same thing...

Comment: I end up using the public key in pem format.

Comment: Same here... Thanks for your answer!